# Screen focus and who's on top

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have a .net 4 WinForms app. The main screen shows a list of jobs that are either retrieved by polling a WCF service, or manual entry by the user.

The user can also view various forms to do with the jobs, who carries them out, the job location etc.

However when these forms pop up over the main screen, they intermittently vanish behind it. I assume this is because the polling refreshes the main screen's job list and gives it the focus.

I initially solved this by setting TopMost = true for all the "child" forms, but when I found it even sent InputDialogs to the back, I began to think I was going about it all wrong.

Is there another way to stop the main screen elbowing itself to the front? I have been told not to use MDI for this app, so it's not an option.

Comment: Can you share the code that you use to display the child windows?

Comment: Refreshing a control doesn't claim focus, so what are you doing exactly with the polling results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the [Child Forms Owner Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). or when you [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) the Form pass in the Parent Form at that Time.

From above Link:

> Owned forms are also never displayed behind their owner form. You can use owned forms for windows such as find and replace windows, which should not disappear when the owner form is selected. To determine the forms that are owned by a parent form, use the OwnedForms property.

Comment: Thanks! Forms are now showing fine, but the InputBoxes are still popping to the back. Guess I'll have to write my own.

Comment: @SteveCav Are you using the Standard InputBox? if so it should be Modal to the creating Form.

Comment: Using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox from Winforms is NOT modal, possibly because it's being called from a Controller class. I rolled my own, set the owner and topmost properties and solved it that way.

Comment: @SteveCav Ok, glad you got it figured out